# Getting video to show up in IE and FF

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I'm setting up oneweekfatloss.com but having trouble getting video to show up.

It works in Chrome and Safari, but not in IE and FF.  I've created an mp4 and .ogv file.

Am I doing something wrong with my html?

```
 <video width="720px" height="420px" autoplay>
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/paleojumpstart/paleovideos/Paleo+Sales+Video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/paleojumpstart/paleovideos/Paleo_Sales_Video-OGV.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
    <object data="https://s3.amazonaws.com/paleojumpstart/paleovideos/Paleo+Sales+Video.mp4" width="720px" height="420px">
        <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/paleojumpstart/paleovideos/Paleo_Sales_Video-Flash.flv" width="720px" height="420px">
    </object>
</video>
```

EDIT:  I realized I hadn't set the permissions correctly on Amazon s3.  That solved the FF problem.  IE's still not working, though.

EDIT2:  IE will play the video if I open the page locally, but not from my server.

Comment: Does the mp4 filenames contain `+`? If filenames contain spaces encode them URLs as `%20`.

Comment: I tried doing that.  Chrome still plays the video, IE still doesn't.

Comment: This webpage lists just about everything you need to run HTML5 videos: http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody

Answer (score 0):

See these pages for format compatibility: [WebM](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webm), [Mp4](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4), and [Ogg](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ogv). FireFox only supports WebM and Ogg. IE does not support the standard `<source` tag. Here is a code excerpt from MSDN:

```
<video width="400" height="300" poster="frame.png" autoplay controls loop>
    <source src="video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora,
     vorbis"'>
    <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E,
     mp4a.40.2"'>
 </video>
```

You can test video format campatability on this page: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/VideoFormatSupport/Default.html

Comment: I removed my W3schools link in favor of caniuse.com

Comment: Shouldn't firefox play the .ogv file?
If IE doesn't support the <source> tag, how do I tell IE which video to play?  Using "src=" inside the video tag?  Shouldn't the <object> tag tell IE which to use?

Comment: I'm not sure what your objective of the `<object>` is. Are you serving the video files with the correct MIME type(s)? What version of FF are you testing in?

Comment: The FF version is 18.0.1
Honestly I used the <object> tag because that's what W3schools said to do.

Comment: 1) Don't listen to W3schools. HTML5Rocks is a better resource. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

Comment: I realized I hadn't set the permissions correctly on Amazon s3.  That solved the FF problem.  IE's still not working, though.

Comment: I just updated it.  The <object> tag is necessary for the <embed> tag so I can have a flash backup for older browsers, right?

Comment: If the video works in IE locally, check your file paths. Use absolute file paths if possible.